# Is there a way to get the tag of a polymorphic variant as a variable in ReasonML

Tags: generics, polymorphism, variant, reason

I'm looking to see if i can genericize the following code a bit.

```
type recordType = [
  | `Todo(todo, idFunction)
  | `TodoItem(todoItem, idFunction)


let commitItemToSchema = (normalizedSchema, recordType) => {
  switch(recordType){
  | `Todo    (todo,     idFun) => {...normalizedSchema, todo:       addOrModifyById(normalizedSchema.todo,       todo,       idFun)}
  | `TodoItem(todoItem, idFun) => {...normalizedSchema, todoItem:   addOrModifyById(normalizedSchema.todoItem,   todoItem,   idFun)}
  };
};
```

Is there a way that I can get the `\'Todo` or the `'TodoItem` from the variant as a variable?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the types of everything shown in the code sample?

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you showed us the complete set of types. OCaml/BuckleScript/ReasonML do support polymorphic types. Here is simple type and value declaration using a polymorphic type in ReasonML.

```
type wrapper('a) = {
  item: 'a,
  details: string
};

let x = {item: 1, details: "This is an int"};
```

Here are two kinds of functions that take a `wrapper` with an unrestricted type `'a` and a `wrapper` with a restricted type `'a` as `int`.

```
let unrestrictedType = (x: wrapper('a)) => {
  Js.log(x);
};

let restrictedType = (x: wrapper(int)) => {
  Js.log(x);
};
```

Answer (score -1):

If the variant could be passed as variable, it would lose type check in that case. I don't think ReasonML support that.